# How can I get each cell value of each row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, tablerow

I'm adding rows dinamically in my WebPage and at one moment I want to get the value of each cell in a row.

This is the declaration of my row:

```
<tr class="template-upload fade">
<td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
<td class="title"><label>Andar: <input name="andar" required></label></td>
</tr>
```

As you see, my rows have two cells: name and title. I'm trying to get the value of "name" cell and value of the input "andar" using jQuery.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('.template-upload tr').each(function () {
        var item = $(this); //this should represent one row

        var name = item.find('.name').text();
        var andar = item.find('input:text[name=andar]').val();
});
```

However, I'm not getting anything in this two variable.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: If you use your JS as it is, you will only be able to capture the last value in the last table row because you're basically overwriting the values of the variables.

Try pushing them into an array :)

Comment: How do you intend to use the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you just needed to remove the `tr` from your selector. Your row already has the class `.template-upload` so `$('.template-upload tr')` doesn't exist:

```
$('.template-upload').each(function () {
        var item = $(this); //this should represent one row
        var name = item.find('.name').text();
        var andar = item.find('input:text[name=andar]').val();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XwZJB/1/)**

Comment: Oh man! I was so close! but many thanks! I hope it also helps someone else! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tr` from your selector.

```
$('.template-upload')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your selector is right? Looking at it your selector is `.template-upload tr` which means you're looking for the `tr` elements *inside* the element with the `.template-upload` class.

I think you'd be wanting:

```
$('tr.template-upload').each(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.template-upload` *IS* your `tr`

Change your selector to something like:

```
$('.template-upload').each(function(node){ /* logic */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo...

```
$('tr.template-upload').each(function () {
    ...
});
```